# Access to internal infrastructure from Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows

If I run `Docker` (`Docker for Desktop`, 2.0.0.3 on `Windows 10`), then access to internal infrastructure and containers is fine. I can easily do
`docker pull internal.registry:5005/container:latest`
But ones I enable `Kubernetes` there, I completely lose an access to internal infrastructure and `[Errno 113] Host is unreachable` in `Kubernetes` itself or `connect: no route to host` from `Docker` appears.

I have tried several ways, including switching of `NAT` from `DockerNAT` to `Default Switch`. That one doesn't work without restart and restart changes it back to `DockerNAT`, so, no luck here. [This option](https://anandthearchitect.com/2018/01/06/windows-10-how-to-setup-nat-network-for-hyper-v-guests/) also seems not to work.

Comment: Internal infra DNS is typically and led by some on-prem DNS server. The OS (Win10) is configured to redirect all requests to this internal DNS. It sounds like when you enable K8S the configuration is having no affect. W/ K8S turned off are you able to access the network configuration and view the DNS server values? As a next step walk through https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/ and see if anything from the official troubleshooting docs helps at all.

Comment: unfortunately, not much help from this link as no errors in logs. and even if I set internal `DNS` to internal IP, not much of the help

Answer (score 0):

let's start from the basics form the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/kubernetes/):

1. Please make sure you meet all the prerequisites and all other instructions were met.
2. Also you can use this [guide](https://learnk8s.io/blog/installing-docker-and-kubernetes-on-windows/). It has more info with details pointing to what might have gone wrong in your case.

If the above won't help, there are few other things to consider:

1. In case you are using a virtual machine, make sure that the IP you are referring to is the one of the `docker-engines’` host and not the one on which the client is running.
2. Try to add `tmpnginx` in `docker-compose`.
3. Try to delete the pki directory in `C:\programdata\DockerDesktop` (first stop Docker, delete the dir and than start Docker). The directory will be recreated and `k8s-app=kube-dns` labels should work fine.

Please let me know if that helped.